How to avoid repeating blocks in Hydra configs
A commonly occuring pattern in my config files is repeating certain items with minor changes. For example, let us assume I would like to instantiate three data loaders, one for train, test and validation. I would like to perform minor changes for each loader.
loaders:
  train:
    _partial_: true
    _target_: torch.utils.data.DataLoader
    batch_size: 32
    num_workers: 8
    pin_memory: true
    persistent_workers: true
    shuffle: true
  val:
    _partial_: true
    _target_: torch.utils.data.DataLoader
    batch_size: 64
    num_workers: 8
    pin_memory: true
    persistent_workers: true
    shuffle: true
  test:
    _partial_: true
    _target_: torch.utils.data.DataLoader
    batch_size: 64
    num_workers: 8
    pin_memory: true
    persistent_workers: true
    shuffle: false


The config files get really bulky if I start repeating entries this way, so I would be interested in a simpler / more elegant solution.
I tried the following but
loaders:
  train:
    _partial_: true
    _target_: torch.utils.data.DataLoader
    batch_size: 32
    num_workers: 8
    pin_memory: true
    persistent_workers: true
    shuffle: true
  val: ${loaders.train} # mostly the same as the training loader
    batch_size: 64 # but with the following override
  test: ${loaders.train} # mostly the same as the training loader
    batch_size: 64 # but with this
    shuffle: false  # and this


I get the error mapping values are not allowed here.

The error you are getting is simply because your attempt is not valid YAML
You can use the Extending Configs pattern.
Example application extending configs using a yaml file as a base here.
An alternative (similar) approach is to utilize Structured Configs to set your default values for that node.
You can follow the Structured Configs tutorial assuming you have completed the basic tutorial.
The last page in that tutorial is about using a Structured config as a schema. It has a link to an example application.
I suggest you don't rush to copy paste the examples buy go through the Basic and Structured Configs tutorials to understand the basic concepts of Hydra config composition.

Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, browsing the links you have shared, I couldn't devise a proper structure to tackle the problem I'm currently having. I would appreciate an example, could you share one?

I updated the answer to include links to example apps.

I came across the merge operator <<, which turned out (in my opinion) a very elegant solution to the problem I am having.
What is the << (double left arrow) syntax in YAML called, and where's it specified?
Here's how I applied it:
_base_loader: &base_loader
  _partial_: true
  _target_: torch.utils.data.DataLoader
  batch_size: 32
  num_workers: 8
  pin_memory: true
  persistent_workers: true
  shuffle: true

loaders:
  train:
    <<: *base_loader
  val:
    <<: *base_loader
    batch_size: 64 # but with the following override
  test:
    <<: *base_loader
    batch_size: 64
    shuffle: false


The problem is that this is evaluated when the YAML is loaded. This means that config override will not do what you think. for example if you override _base_loader.partial to false from the command line, it will not change anything in the copied loaders.

@OmryYadan That was the exact problem I faced. And I just noticed that you're the main developer of OmegaConf and Hydra, thank you so much for being around here and answering the questions :)
